Segmentation fault problem encountered when using umm_malloc library
I used the umm_malloc library on github, which is a dynamic memory allocation library suitable for embedded systems. I wrote a test function, but it reported an error. The following is my test function. I think it is completely correct in terms of function, but why is it reporting a segmentation error?
umm_malloc github url:(https://github.com/rhempel/umm_malloc/tree/master)
#include "umm_malloc.h"
#include "stdio.h"

unsigned char UMM_MALLOC_CFG_HEAP_ADDR[16 * 1024] __attribute__((aligned(4))) ;

uint32_t UMM_MALLOC_CFG_HEAP_SIZE = 16 * 1024;

int main(void)
{
    umm_init();

    int *arr = (int *)umm_malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    if (arr == NULL) {
        printf("umm malloc failed!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        arr[i] = i + 1;
        printf("arr[%d] = %d\n", i, arr[i]);
    }

    umm_free(arr);
    printf("umm free finish!\n");

    return 0;
}

output:
$ ./a.exe
Segmentation fault


The usage says you do that at link time.   What is link time?  Have you tried using umm_init_heap() instead?  Don't cast void pointers.  It's not necessary in C and may hide type problems.  Is this a 32-bit platform?  If not have you tried aligned(8)?

One of the tests do char test_umm_heap[0x2000][UMM_BLOCK_BODY_SIZE]; void *UMM_MALLOC_CFG_HEAP_ADDR = &test_umm_heap;  Btw, it's undefined behavior,  to index outside the dimensions of the array. I don't know if something  is angry when you define it as a char [] when it expects a void *.

What does your debugger tell you, where the error happens?

Go through step by step to indicate where could lead to this potential issue, segmentation error, in your umm_malloc library:
Define Block Management Macros
#define UMM_NBLOCK(b) (UMM_BLOCK(b).header.used.next)
#define UMM_PBLOCK(b) (UMM_BLOCK(b).header.used.prev)
#define UMM_NFREE(b)  (UMM_BLOCK(b).body.free.next)
#define UMM_PFREE(b)  (UMM_BLOCK(b).body.free.prev)

Memory Allocation
void *umm_malloc(size_t size){
    return umm_multi_malloc(&umm_heap_current, size);
}

Memory Deallocation
void umm_free(void *ptr){
    umm_multi_free(&umm_heap_current, ptr);
}

Memory Initialization
void umm_multi_init(umm_heap *heap) {
    /* Initialize the heap from linker supplied values */

    umm_multi_init_heap(heap, UMM_MALLOC_CFG_HEAP_ADDR, UMM_MALLOC_CFG_HEAP_SIZE);
}

Try to add some debugging statements to check parameters and behavior. E.g.:
void *umm_malloc_core(umm_heap *heap, size_t size) {
    // Add debug prints to check parameters and behavior
    printf("umm_malloc_core called with size %zu\n", size);
    // Original implementation
    ...
}

void umm_free_core(umm_heap *heap, void *ptr) {
    // Add debug prints to check parameters and behavior
    printf("umm_free_core called with ptr %p\n", ptr);

    // Original implementation
    ...
}

And also make ensure that the size requested for allocation does not exceed the available memory in the heap in the implementation of your umm_malloc library currently.
